# Headless Chrome: website Div content to Text, toString or ASCII

Tags: web-scraping, ascii, chromium, headless, google-chrome-headless

I want to scrape text from a dynamically loaded website for which I need dynamic scraping. Because of dynamic loading, options such as `$ lynx --dump google.com` do not seem to work. For this I have used Headless Chrome such that

```
$ Chrome --headless --disable-gpu --no-sandbox --run-all-compositor-stages-before-draw --virtual-time-budget=1000 --window-size=1200,3000 --screenshot http://mtv.com
```

but I cannot find an option to scrape the text out of the website. I am available to all dynamic scraping options to get the text of specific div with some class for instance.

**How can I scape text from a dynamically-loaded website?**

*Example result by the dynamic loading using headless chrome*
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can write JS for Node.js, you can try [puppeteer](https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer), Node.js library to manage headless Chrome:

```js
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async function main() {
  try {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    const [page] = await browser.pages();

    await page.goto('http://www.mtv.com/');

    const data = await page.evaluate(() => {
      return document.querySelector('div.header').innerText;
    });

    console.log(data);

    await browser.close();
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();
```

Output:

```
teen mom 2
```

Answer (score 0):

*The best method would be to directly extract the text from the website.*

If no other method can be found, use OCR (optical character recognition) to extract the text, along the Headless Chrome solution provided in the question.

**Bad option OCR from the screenshot**

```
$ brew install imagemagick

$ brew install tesseract

$ convert input.png -resize 400% -type Grayscale input.tif

$ tesseract -l eng input.tif output
```

[image]

where you could use Regex to find individual pieces of texts. Otherwise, the OCR output is exact but unorganised making it somehow hard to use later, proto to recognition inaccuracies.

Answer (score 0):

The below example echoes `b'teen mom 2'`, demonstrating Python Selenium utilising Headless Chome driver below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import locale
os.environ["PYTHONIOENCODING"] = "utf-8"
myLocale=locale.setlocale(category=locale.LC_ALL, locale="en_GB.UTF-8")

url = "http://mtv.com"
driver = webdriver.Chrome('/Users/hhh/Downloads/chromedriver')
driver.get(url)
SpecialPrice =driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='header']")

myText=SpecialPrice.text
print(myText.encode('utf-8', errors='ignore'))
```